# JFreeChart initial 'zoom'

Tags: java, graph, visualization, jfreechart, graphing

I am using `JFreeChart 1.0.19` to create a timeseries graph. The graph contains both positive and negative values, however when the graph is initially displayed the Y axis always baselines to 0, and therefore I only know about the negative numbers when I manually zoom out.

Is there a way to get JFreeChart to display the full range when it is first drawn.

I have tried:

```
Number maximum = DatasetUtilities.findMaximumRangeValue(data);
Number minimum = DatasetUtilities.findMinimumRangeValue(data);        
((XYPlot)timeSeriesChart.getPlot()).getRangeAxis().setRange(minimum.intValue(),
maximum.intValue());
```

- Setting the range to a static negative min value.
- Googling it

The API doc doesn't seem very clear on why this behaviour is or how to alter it. Any help appreicated.

Comment: Try this: `((XYPlot)timeSeriesChart.getPlot()).getRangeAxis().setAutoRange(true)`

Comment: doesn't seem to have any effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@raul1ro was along the right lines.
I solved this by adding:

```
timeSeriesChart.getXYPlot().getRangeAxis().setDefaultAutoRange(new Range(minimum.doubleValue(), maximum.doubleValue()));
```

Comment: I'm glad I helped